# How to loop through xml string in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an xml string looking something like this

```
<row Name="analog.__VG_SPP3_SFRTPCT" />
<row Name="analog._3305_LIST210_1" />
<row Name="analog._AG_5340_PR14AN" />
<row Name="analog._AG_EPNT_2" />
<row Name="analog._AG_EPNT_SP" />
<row Name="analog._AG_MERC_ERXTES" />
<row Name="analog._AG_ROC_TEST" />
<row Name="analog._AG_ROM1_LOAD" />
<row Name="analog._AG_TEST_CRC1LT" />
<row Name="analog._AG_TEST_CRC1RT" />
<row Name="analog._CWAV_TST_MDP1CV" />
<row Name="analog._CWAV_TST_MDP1CV_LIST" />
```

Trying to generate an option list for a combo box displayed in javascript, I am trying to loop through the xml string in razor to generate it, however I am not quite sure how to or if its even possible, I can do this by splitting the xml into a separate data structure and then looping through that datastructure again in razor. However for performance reasons it would be nice to be able to do this in one go.

```
@model string
@{
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Layout = null;
}
<complete>
    <option value=""><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></option>
    @foreach (var row  in @Model)
    {
        <option value="@(row.Name)">@(row.Name)</option>  
    }
</complete>
```

Comment: i have no idea, but could you ajax it back to the controller to do?

Comment: I guess I could potentially do this in the controller and just have razor pass the string along unchanged back to the ajax caller on the javascript side.

Comment: You could change the controller to give you an IEnumerable<string> with each entry being a row instead of all the rows in a single string.

Comment: you could convert the row to XElement and then fetch the attributes value very easy and output it with razor:
  foreach (...)
 var xmlElement = XElement.Parse(row);
 var name = xmlElement.Attribute("Name").Value;
 ...@name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, here is what I ended up doing in razor, thanks pasty. I encapsulated the output xml string with  on the controller side, then inserted it in a ComboData structure, apparently razor had issues with a pure string, when the data got too large.

controller:

```
var Names = "<rows>" + oService.Names(ID) + "</rows>";
var oComboData = new ComboData(Names);
return View("ComboData", oComboData);
```

viewmodel:

```
public class ComboData
{
    public ComboData(string sString)
    {
        xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(sString);
    }

    public XmlDocument xdoc { get; set; }
}
```

view:

```
@using System.Xml
@using ViewModels; 
@model ComboData
@{
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Layout = null;
}
<complete>
    <option value=""><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></option>
    @foreach (XmlNode node in Model.xdoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
    {
        <option value="@(node.Attributes[0].Value)">@(node.Attributes[0].Value)</option>
    }
</complete>
```